# Lazy loading and multithreading

Tags: c#, ios, multithreading, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to use the iCarousel library in monotouch. I successfully ported the library, everything works perfectly but the application crashes if you enter too many UIImageViews with images inside, which is normal because iCarousel is just like a UIScrollView.

I definitely have to use lazy loading system somehow from a secondary thread and display only 3-4 images at once but I do not know how to make this work smooth.

At this point, I set this in the iCarousel Delegate:

```
bool threadsAlive = true; 

public cDelegate() 
{ 
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( delegate { refresh_visible(); } ); 
} 

public override void DidScroll (iCarousel carousel) 
{ 
        scrolling = true; 
} 

public override void DidEndScrollingAnimation (iCarousel carousel) 
{ 
        scrolling = false;  
        //show images that are currently on the screen 
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( delegate { ShowCurrent();         } ); 
        //hides images that are not on the screen         
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( delegate { hideInvisibleImages(); } ); 
} 

void refresh_visible() 
{ 
        while( threadsAlive ) 
        { 
                while( scrolling ) 
                { 
                        ShowCurrent(); 
                } 
        } 
} 

void refresh_hidden() 
{ 
        while( threadsAlive ) 
        { 
                while( scrolling ) 
                { 
                        hideInvisibleImages(); 
                } 
        } 
} 

public void ShowCurrent() 
{ 
        var          ds = _carousel.DataSource as cDataSource; 
        var left_index  = _carousel.CurrentItemIndex - 1; 
        var right_index = _carousel.CurrentItemIndex + 2; 
        if( left_index  <  0 ) left_index  = 0; 
        if( right_index >= ds.Lista.Count ) right_index = ds.Lista.Count - 1; 
        // 
        for( var i = left_index; i < right_index ; i++ ) 
        { 
                var img = ds.Lista[i]; 
                if( img.Image == null ) 
                { 
                        BeginInvokeOnMainThread( delegate{ 
                                img.Image = UIImage.FromFile( img.UserObject.ToString() ); 
                        }); 
                } 
        } 
} 


void hideInvisibleImages() 
{ 
        Console.WriteLine("ascund!"); 
        var          ds = _carousel.DataSource as cDataSource; 
        var left_index  = _carousel.CurrentItemIndex - 1; 
        var right_index = _carousel.CurrentItemIndex + 2; 
        if( left_index  <  0 ) left_index  = 0; 
        if( right_index >= ds.Lista.Count ) right_index = ds.Lista.Count - 1; 
        // 
        for( var i=0; i<left_index; i++ ) 
        { 
                var img   = ds.Lista[i]; 
                if( img.Image != null ) 
                { 
                        img.Image.Dispose(); 
                        img.Image = null; 
                } 
        } 
        for( var i=right_index; i<ds.Lista.Count; i++ ) 
        { 
                var img   = ds.Lista[i]; 
                if( img.Image != null ) 
                { 
                        img.Image.Dispose(); 
                        img.Image = null; 
                } 
        } 
}
```

The code is actually very simple: there is a main thread that only shows 1 image from the left of the current index and two images in advance, and another thread that cleans all other images, hides them.

It's working, memory is ok, but it's not smooth on the device, it "hangs" a little when I scroll.  There is another way of doing this ? Or maybe I should change the algoritm?

Comment: Maybe you should try not spinning in a hot loop waiting for a bool to become false. This consumes the whole CPU! Insert at least a Thread.Sleep(10) in there.

Comment: This code is broken.   You are accessing UIKit elements from a background thread (hideInvisibleImages) and that will lead to random memory corruption.

Comment: @miguel.de.icaza, you mean that i have to use invokeOnMainThread before img.Image.Dispose() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having a loop that won't allow CPU to any other thread/process and will lead to a very high CPU utilization. This is making it hang when you scroll.

Try using Thread.Sleep(1) or a small sleep time in the refresh_visible method.

Answer (score 2):

**I'm a little confused how your scrolling works, but I think that the below code can give you a decent starting point on how to fix this issue.**

As usr pointed out in the comment section, you're constantly spinning in a loop and refreshing the image as fast as possible (if I understand your code correctly):

```
void refresh_visible() 
{ 
        while( threadsAlive ) 
        { 
                while( scrolling ) 
                { 
                        ShowCurrent(); 
                } 
        } 
} 

void refresh_hidden() 
{ 
        while( threadsAlive ) 
        { 
                while( scrolling ) 
                { 
                        hideInvisibleImages(); 
                } 
        } 
}
```

It seems that it may be a good idea to have the appropriate refresh rate whatever scrolling. You should implement a refresh rate that's somewhere between 24 and 30 frames per second.

Something like this may be in order:

```
using System.Threading;

class YourClass
{
    // Tick every 42 millisecond or about 24 times per second
    private readonly int _refreshRate = 42;

    private volatile bool _scrolling;
    private Timer _timer;
    YourClass()
    {
        _timer = new Timer(TimerTick, null, 0, _refreshRate);
    }

    public void TimerTick(object state)
    {
        if (_scrolling)
        {
            ShowCurrent();
            HideInvisibleImages();
        }
    }

    void ShowCurrent()
    {
        //...
    }

    void HideInvisibleImages()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Please note that if you're creating and destroying a lot of `YourClass` instances, you should also dispose of the `Timer` object when you're done with it. The `Timer`'s delegate will hold a reference to the `YourClass` instance and it will prevent it from being garbage collected.